# highcharts y-axis granularity

Tags: highcharts, granularity

I am in a situation to show highcharts with yaxis tickpositions(this.tickPositions) should be closely aligned to min and max of data points,[screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqVmS.png)

by default Highcharts generates tick positions far beyond the min and max of datapoints, However, I have found one link that compensates this situation but this fails at some point

Any help will be appreciated.

[fiddle1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590538/highcharts-yaxis-tickinterval-to-max-data/36600756#36600756)

Comment: You can set axis min and max limit based on your data and adjust ticks with those. If you data is static, it can be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uxfnsy3q/, if you add data dynamically then after updating data, update axis property with axis.update() method.
If you share the code, it will be more understandable what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried? What precisely do you mean by "closely aligned to min and max"? Have you looked at the docs?  There are a lot of different things that can be done to solve this, but you need to be more specific about what you have, what you want, and what isn't working.